# Adding Two Numbers using Two Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, addition

> I want to add just two numbers using two threads,but i didn't understand where i am wrong.
>    My output is wrong.And i know problem is with synchronized but not able solve.

```
import java.io.*;

class GFG {
public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    final Addition a=new Addition();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run(){
            try {
               a.add(1,10); 
            } catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });

    Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run(){
            try {
                a.add(1,4);
            } catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    });

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}

public static class Addition{
    int a, b;
    int sum=0;
    public void add(int a, int b) throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            for (int i=a;i<=b;i++){
                sum=sum+i;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            System.out.println("Sum="+sum);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
 Sum=55
 Sum=65
```

And by seeing output I can say that... After completing the task of THREAD t1, THREAD t2 is adding its result to the t1...??

Comment: You're using `a` in both threads...

Comment: To understand what you want to get, what is the final result that you are expecting from t1 and t2?

Comment: What is your intended result?

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue or helped you with your problem, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: t1 should give me 55
t2 should give me 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem - beside that the code is obviously misleading on purpose - is that `sum` is a class member of `Addition`. As you're using the same instance of `Addition` in both threads, the state of sum is shared between the threads. That is the second thread will not start summing up with `0` but with the result of the previous addition `55`. This leads to the observed output.

If you change `Addition` to the following the program will behave as expected.

```
public static class Addition {
  int a, b;

  public void add(int a, int b) throws InterruptedException {
    int sum = 0;
    synchronized (this) {
      for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
        sum = sum + i;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      System.out.println("Sum=" + sum);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand...but why we are making "a" and "b" as final int??

Comment: You mean the method parameters? It's good practice to make parameters final to avoid accidental overwriting of input parameters. In your example the final has no effect. The only important thing to note is, that the method parameters are shadowing the class' members `a` and `b`. The class members could actually be removed as they are not used in your example. Actually the `final` was added automatically by my IDE. I removed it from the above example...

Comment: Yes, you are right!! There is no use of class members here...Understood now.. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

This was designed by someone to be deliberately misleading (Perhaps it belongs in puzzles overflow?).  The indenting doesn't match the braces.

You can tell that "sum" will only be initialized to zero once and never re-initialized to zero because Addition is only constructed once (new Addition only happens once).

If you want the Addition object to work independently, set some to zero inside the synchronized.

I kinda hate that I answered this because it's obviously a constructed puzzle/homework type of thing, but you can have this one as a freebie I guess

Comment: Why/how does that affect the behaviour in this case?

Comment: Actually the big clue is that Addition is only instantiated once, so sum will only ever be set to zero once.  I'll clarify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same instance of `Addition: "a"` and although the `Addition's` global variables `"a" and "b"` are hidden but `"sum"` is not.

Answer (score 0):

- The two threads use the same instance of class `Addition`.
- The unique instance of  class `Addition` has the variable `sum` which is share between threads t1 and t2.
- According each thread is running they are changing the value of `sum` and the result is merged.

I ran your program and made some change to add logs, as you can see:

```
  public static class Addition{
    int a, b;
    private int sum=0;

    public void add(int a, int b, int id) throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("INIT ADD t:[" + id + "]");

        synchronized(this){
            for (int i=a;i<=b;i++){
                System.out.println("Sum Before t:[" + id + "] i:[" + i + "]=" + sum);
                sum=sum + i;
                System.out.println("Sum After t:[" + id + "] i:[" + i + "]=" + sum);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum t:[" + id + "]=" + sum);
     }

  }
```

The log confirms that i told you, the variable sum is affected each time by each tread. Here the log:

```
INIT ADD t:[1]
Sum Before t:[1] i:[1]=0
INIT ADD t:[2]
Sum After t:[1] i:[1]=1
Sum Before t:[1] i:[2]=1
Sum After t:[1] i:[2]=3
Sum Before t:[1] i:[3]=3
Sum After t:[1] i:[3]=6
Sum Before t:[1] i:[4]=6
Sum After t:[1] i:[4]=10
Sum Before t:[1] i:[5]=10
Sum After t:[1] i:[5]=15
Sum Before t:[1] i:[6]=15
Sum After t:[1] i:[6]=21
Sum Before t:[1] i:[7]=21
Sum After t:[1] i:[7]=28
Sum Before t:[1] i:[8]=28
Sum After t:[1] i:[8]=36
Sum Before t:[1] i:[9]=36
Sum After t:[1] i:[9]=45
Sum Before t:[1] i:[10]=45
Sum After t:[1] i:[10]=55
Sum t:[1]=55
Sum Before t:[2] i:[1]=55
Sum After t:[2] i:[1]=56
Sum Before t:[2] i:[2]=56
Sum After t:[2] i:[2]=58
Sum Before t:[2] i:[3]=58
Sum After t:[2] i:[3]=61
Sum Before t:[2] i:[4]=61
Sum After t:[2] i:[4]=65
Sum t:[2]=65
```

As you synchronized `for` block, the second thread (`t2`) start to add and store the result into `sum`, but `sum` has the result of `t1`(55) at the begin of `for`.

So, according with this log, what is the behavior that you want to get?

Comment: @drp, i add the information that you ask me. Thanks. But i´m not sure what the user want to get.

Comment: Have you tried your proposed change? I doubt that it will have any effect as `sum` will still be shared between the threads, with or without the class being `static`.

Comment: @drp i made it and changed my answer. Thanks.